# Image input onclick event being fired when enter button Pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xhtml

I have a strange problem where an onclick event on an input image is being fired when i hit enter in input text box

```
<form id="MyForm" action="/someaction">

<input type="image" src="someimage.jpg" onclick="doStuff();$('#MyForm').submit();" />

<input type="text" name="textInput"/>

</form>
```

When the cursor is in the text box and i hit enter, rather than the form being submitted it calls the onclick event on the image input.

Any ideas whats going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onclick event is fired on input images when you hit enter. I'd wrapping an `<img>` in an `<a>`, as since you're separately calling `submit()`, the input element is made redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I believe pressing the 'enter' button counts as a click in many cases, including links. If you want your action to be performed only when the mouse is used, then consider using onmousedown or onmouseup instead of onclick, I'd suggest the latter in your case.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar problem and it was only happening in IE. Chrome and firefox were working just fine. When hitting enter from the input box, it would trigger the first input type="image" which we did not want because it would send multiple requests to IE and after hitting enter a few times it would crash.

The quick and easy work around, though not the best solution, we used was to put a dummy input type="image" with an onclick return value of false before the other ones so that the one being triggered wouldn't actually fire off a request. Not the correct root solution but a good temporary one.